# cant get Java variable into PHP

Tags: java, php, android, variables

I am trying to pass a variable from Java to PHP but whatever i do, it just doesnt work.
I dont even understand how i am able to see the Java variable in PHP...
I am very confused, and have no idea what i should do next.

my current java code looks like this;

```
    public void mahGPSbutton() {


    Button myGPS_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.GPS_button);
    myGPS_button.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    myGPS_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                                                                                              //#
        public void onClick(View v) {   
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); //#
            LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {                                                      //#
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location, String url) {
                    double MyLat = location.getLatitude();
                    double MyLong = location.getLongitude();
                    double MyAlt = location.getAltitude();
                    String MyProvider = location.getProvider();
                    float MyAccuracy = location.getAccuracy();
                    Object URI = "http://192.168.1.41/School/Binder.php?MyLat="+MyLat;
                    TextView TV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gPstextView1);
                    TV.setText("Your current location is: " + MyLat + "\n" + MyLong + "\n" + MyAlt + "\n" + MyProvider + "\n" + MyAccuracy);

                    try
                    {
                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.41/School/Binder.php?myLat="+ MyLat);
                        httppost.setURI((java.net.URI) URI);
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
                        }
                }
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}                                    //#
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}                                                             //#
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
                //#
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            };                                                                                                                //#
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                                                                                                              //#
        }                                                                                                                     //#
    }); 
}                                                                                                                             //#
```

and the php file on the server side:

```
<?php
$LAT_VARIABLE = $_GET['MyLat'];
$LONG_VARIABLE = $_GET['MyLong'];
$ALT_VARIABLE = $_GET['MyAlt'];
$PRO_VARIABLE = $_GET['MyProvider'];
$ACC_VARIABLE = $_GET['MyAccuracy'];

echo "Number 1: ".$LAT_VARIABLE."";
echo "Can you see the value?";

?>
```

by the way, i tried to use one this way

```
String URL = "http://192.168.1.41/School/Binder.php?MyLat="+MyLat;
```

and downstairs on the Try / catch place

```
httppost.setURI(URL);
```

but the last line gives me one error, with says change the URL to URI but then the line with String URL = .... give me another error with says to change it to string...
so i could somebody help me, or give me some ideas what i should do ?
and how i should see the value of the variable? just entering `http://192.168.1.41/School/Binder.php` right?

btw yes, i am doing this all locally both server and android device are on the same network.

Thanks in advice...
Regards

Comment: I see a couple of casting mistakes in your code.  URI should be String  or of Type URI.

Comment: On the other Hand I think you will have a ClassCastException here: httppost.setURI((java.net.URI) URI);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your PHP code to be like this:

```
<?php
$LAT_VARIABLE = $_REQUEST['MyLat'];
$LONG_VARIABLE = $_REQUEST['MyLong'];
$ALT_VARIABLE = $_REQUEST['MyAlt'];
$PRO_VARIABLE = $_REQUEST['MyProvider'];
$ACC_VARIABLE = $_REQUEST['MyAccuracy'];

echo "Number 1: ".$LAT_VARIABLE."";
echo "Can you see the value?";

error_log("Lat: " . $LAT_VARIABLE, 0);

?>
```

This isn't the major issue though.  I ran your code with some slight modification, and got:

`android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

This is a classic problem in Android.  You need to run your network code in an `AsyncTask` or in a `Thread`.

I got past this with an AsyncTask like this:

```
    locationManager = (LocationManager) MainActivity.this
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); // #

    clickableButtonWithBorder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

                    locationListener = new LocationListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onStatusChanged(String provider,
                                int status, Bundle extras) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                            double MyLat = location.getLatitude();
                            double MyLong = location.getLongitude();
                            double MyAlt = location.getAltitude();
                            String MyProvider = location.getProvider();
                            float MyAccuracy = location.getAccuracy();
                            Object URI = "http://localhost/Binder.php?MyLat="
                                    + MyLat;
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Your current location is: " + MyLat
                                            + "\n" + MyLong + "\n" + MyAlt
                                            + "\n" + MyProvider + "\n"
                                            + MyAccuracy,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            NetworkOperation op = new NetworkOperation(MyLat);
                            op.execute("");

                        };
                    }; // #

                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

            // #
        }                                                                                                                     //#
}); 
    }      

    private class NetworkOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    double MyLat;

    public NetworkOperation(double lat)
    {
        MyLat = lat;
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "http://10.33.146.21/Binder.php?MyLat="
                            + MyLat);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
        }
        return "Executed";
    }

}
```

Finally, I noticed that you used "MyLat" in some places and "myLat" in others.  Make them all "MyLat". and it works for me:

```
[Thu Jan 02 16:03:01 2014] [error] [client 10.35.134.163] Lat: 33.9305431
```

Comment: `$_REQUEST` is bad. You should always know where the input data is coming from

Comment: Hello!
Thank you very much, i am trying this right now, i will let u hear from me more soon

Comment: Hi again, i did it like how u said (with small changes) and im not sure if it DOES work or not...
I am able to see my current location on the phone self, but not on the Binder.php file
by to way, i have checked if my device does indeed make contact with the server, and yes it does, i can see that they are contacing eachother, so i belive its not the connection between them...

Any idea what i shall do now?

Comment: Nevermind, it looks that echo wont print the results, but saveing right into the db worked.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you're POSTing in Java but trying to GET in PHP.